# live camera feed from another website - iframe

Tags: html, iframe, feed

I'm trying to incude the live feed images from these pages:
    http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/webcam.php - img src: tincam1.jpg,
    http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/wxwebcam.php - img src: TinCam.jpg,
    http://www.falakro.meteodrama.gr/webcam.php - image src: tincam1.jpg,
    http://www.falakro.meteodrama.gr/wxwebcam.php - image src: TinCam.jpg,

to this page:
    http://snowclub.gr/test_forum2/index.php?app=ccs&module=pages&section=pages&folder=&id=19.

I've tried to work it out using iframe (as with the other live camera feeds from another website as you can see by visiting the URL above) but the live feed image src is the same for every 2 pages so I can have only 2 different images on my website (I want all 4 of them).
Any suggestions on how to manage this (preferrably non-PHP)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing the main point. There are 2 different website addresses using similar image names that refreshes every set of intervals.

I guess that clears why you are only getting 2 images. See the address. It is different

Comment: Yes, I saw that. So what do you suggest as a solution to my issue??

Comment: when you save the image, you can change the file name and put it all in one folder - I don't know how the program is written but may be adding an _1.jpg, _2.jpg to the file name wouldn't be a big deal and may be you can overwrite it once you reach required number of files.